# Dynamic/ dependent input box

Tags: javascript

How can i make a input box that appears only when i select a value from a drop down box?

thank you,
Sebastian

EDIT-1:

thanks guys for the help.
but the example from sushil bharwani is best for me, because i also need to display a text with the text box.

but with that example i have a problem. both the text and the text box look like they are in the same cell, so they are messing up my layout for the form.
Got any ideas?

thanks,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/88791-show-hide-text-form-field-based-drop-down-selection

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to define the select's onchange attribute to check the text (or value) of the selected option:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function checkSelect(el) {
  if (el.options[el.selectedIndex].text.length > 0)
   document.getElementById('text1').style.display = 'block';
  else
   document.getElementById('text1').style.display = 'none';
 }
</script>

<select onchange="checkSelect(this)">
 <option></option>
 <option>Val 1</option>
</select> 

<input type="text" id="text1" style="display:none" />
```

For further details, you can read more about HTML DOM objects and how to access them via javascript:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

Consider that the textbox should show when choice 2 is selected

The dropdown box

```
<select id="dropBox" size="1" onChange="dropBoxChng();">
    <option value="1">Choice 1</option>
    <option value="2">Choice 2</option>
    <option value="3">Choice 3</option>
    <option value="4">Other</option>
</select>
```

the input box

```
<input type="text" id="txtBox" style="display:none">
```

the onchange function

```
function dropBoxChng(){
    if(document.getElementById('dropBox').value == 2){
        document.getElementById('txtBox').style.display = 'block';
    }
}​
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aAapQ/6/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
input {
    font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    display: block;
    padding: 4px;
    border: solid 1px #85b1de; 
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #EDF2F7;
}

option {
 color: white;
 background-color: blue;
}

.even {
  background-color: red;
  color: blue;
}
</style>
<script>
function replaceElement(){
    var select=document.getElementById('mySelectMenu');
    var chosenoption=select.options[select.selectedIndex];
    var oChild= document.getElementsByTagName('input');  
    var br1= document.getElementsByTagName('br');
    var temp=br1.length; 
    for(var i=0; i<temp; i++){ 
       alert("remove input box " + i);
       myform.removeChild(oChild[0]); 
       alert("remove br " + i);
       myform.removeChild(br1[0]);
    }
    for(var i=0; i<chosenoption.value; i++){
       alert("add br " + i);
       var br2 = document.createElement('br');
       myform.appendChild(br2); 
       alert("add input box " + i);
       var oNewChild=document.createElement('input');
       oNewChild.type='text';
       oNewChild.size=6;
       myform.appendChild(oNewChild);  
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="myform">
<select id="mySelectMenu" onchange="replaceElement()">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2" class="even">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4" class="even">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```